# Delete files tracked in git stash and then git stash pop

Tags: git, github

I did `git stash`. I then did `git stash pop` but got the following error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>     [proj].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[user].xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
>     Leaflet-[proj]/Leaflet.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/[user].xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
>   Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting

I committed my changes. I tried `git stash pop` again to no avail. I then removed the files with `git rm --cached` and committed those deletions. `git stash pop` now gives `error: refusing to lose untracked file`.

git status:

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/temp' by 2 commits.   (use "git
>   push" to publish your local commits)
>
> Unmerged paths:   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)   (use
>   "git add/rm ..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
>
> deleted by us:
>   [proj].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[user].xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
>     deleted by us:
>   [proj]/xcuserdata/[user].xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deleted files in your stash, then the stashed changes cannot be merged because it can't merge to non-existent files. It sounds like when you said you committed your changes earlier you might have done a `git add` but not a `git commit`? After doing a `git commit` running `git stash pop` should have worked. If you did do that and it didn't I'm not sure what the issue was because you haven't provided enough info at that point.

You have a few options now. The safest is probably to do a `git stash branch <branchname>`. That will checkout your last stash onto a new branch. From there you can edit it as you like, commit your changes to the branch, then merge it back to the branch you were working on.

If you just want to discard your latest stash you can `git stash drop`.

If you want to discard all stashes: `git stash clear`.